# Prevent BroadCast in android when state changed by Application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my system I am monitoring Ringer mode change by implementing BroadCastReceiver.
onReceive I changes accordingly in my application.

But when Ringer mode is changed by my application, I don't want to do any thing in OnReceive.

Is there any way to detect this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can keep a static flag and set it to true, while your app changes mode. And in onReceive check that boolean, if flase, then perform something you want. if true, just make it false.

Comment: One way is you maintain a value in your app saying that this changes has been made by your app and when OnReceive gets called simply compare the value and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you maintain a value in your app saying that this changes has been made by your app and when OnReceive gets called simply compare the value and proceed accordingly.